# Internet Explorer Error Message When Running Applet

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jre, java-applet

When I trying to run an applet on Internet Explorer 11 release, I am getting an error message as shown in the enclosed screenshot.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What happens if you click on it?

Comment: @Scorpion99 It opens the Microsoft site mentioning activeX, but no link to download any files.

Comment: Is your IE11 up to date?

Comment: @Scorpion99 Yes, it is updated.